# bash automatically executing a tool-specific configuration file on login

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables, dotfiles

My project uses an internal tool on Linux, that uses a file called .spacerc for configuring some environmental variables.

The strange thing is, whenever I start a (non-login interactive) bash shell - whether via PuTTy, or via executing $SHELL, or via a python script executing pty.spawn($SHELL) - it reads in .spacerc and sets the environmental variables as specified in it.  (And yes, $SHELL is /bin/bash.)

It appears that .spacerc is read before .bashrc is executed (at least the one in the local user directory).

I can't find any info on line that indicates why bash would automatically read in an arbitrary file called .spacerc.

Why might this be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Since this happens on non-login interactive shell,s your first step is to examine `~/.bashrc` and, if it exists on your sysetm, `/etc/bash.bashrc` and see what they execute.

Comment: Nothing in any `*bashrc*` anywhere that refers to a .spacerc file, or that spawns any tool that might.

Comment: Also, just edited OP to add that it appears that .spacerc is read before .bashrc is executed.

Comment: Are these unwanted environment variables specific, as per the question, to "non-login interactive) shell shell" or do they occur for all shells?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the capability to log into this system in a different way.

Comment: Yes, you do.  Run `bash --login` and you will get a login shell.  For our purposes, though, run `bash --login --norc --noprofile` and see if the unwanted environmental variables are still there.

Comment: `bash --login`: They're there.
`bash --login --norc --noprofile`: They're not there.

Comment: That means we are making progress.  Next, try `bash --login --norc` and, if the unwanted environment variables are there, then the problem is with one of the profile files:  `/etc/profile` or `~/.bash_profile`.  If you don't have the latter, then check  `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile`.

Comment: Check **all** of the files listed in [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery solved:
The tool owner added a script to /etc/profile.d directory (which is executed on every shell start), that reads in the tool-specific configuration file.